# How to make scanner read my boolean outcome?

Tags: java

I am making a program with alot of boolean true or false statement, I want the output of the boolean to be read by scanner and want it as some kind of output, Is there way to do it

Ex:

```
if (day == 1){System.out.print("first");}

if (month == 1){System.out.println("Your birthday is " + day + " January");}
```

pretty much I ask the user to input an number and it will convert it to the actual month's name and it will tell them their birthday by converting numbers, but when I do the way I am its just going to print it out. I want to make Scanner read the input 1 as first and want it to write as "Your birthday is first January"

Answer (score 0):

You can use a switch statement and set your response string based on the number they entered and use that in your print statement.

```
String response;

switch(day){
  case 1: response = "first";
    break;
  case 2: response = "second";
    break;
  /*
  And so on...
  */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this approach:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String[] months = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Type month: ");

    int month = 0;
    while(sc.hasNextInt()) {
        month = sc.nextInt();
        // get month from 1 to 12
        if (month > 0 && month < 12) {
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Type valid month: ");
            continue;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Type day: ");
    while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
        int day = sc.nextInt();
        int numDays = 0;
        switch (month) {
            case 1:
            case 3:
            case 5:
            case 7:
            case 8:
            case 10:
            case 12:
                numDays = 31; break;
            case 4:
            case 6:
            case 9:
            case 11:
                numDays = 30; break;
            case 2: numDays = 28; break;
        }
        // get day taking under consideration amount of days in the month
        if (day > 0 && day <= numDays) {
            System.out.println("Your birthday is " + day + " " + months[month-1]);
            return;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Type valid day: ");
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```